# Angular Material tab change (previous and current tab)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

Is there a way we can check tab change or detect if previous tab is equal to current tab? Let us say my current tab is 1 and then I change tab which current value now is 2, how do we check if previous is equal to the current tab without saving it to a local storage?

```ts
 tabChange(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
    this.selectedIndex = event.index;
    this.selectedBrokerProperty = [];
    this.files = [];
  }
```

Comment: Is a property on the controller "local storage"? I'd just add a `lastTabIndex: number` property. Then in `tabChange` you could compare `lastTabIndex` to `event.index`. At the end, `this.lastTabIndex = event.index;` and you're good to go. Maybe in `ngOnInit` you could set `this.lastTabIndex = <reference to MatTabGroup>.selectedIndex;` to initialize to the correct state.

Comment: can you post that as an answer Sir , so I can vote. Thanks.

Comment: can you we do that just inside the tab change mthod?

Comment: No; it needs to store the value of `lastTabIndex` outside of the event handler or it would reset on every tab change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just add a `lastTabIndex: number` property to the same class that has `tabChange`. Then in `tabChange` you could compare `this.lastTabIndex` (previous) to `event.index` (current).

At the end of `tabChange`, add `this.lastTabIndex = event.index;` and you're good to go.

Maybe in `ngOnInit` you could set `this.lastTabIndex = <reference to MatTabGroup>.selectedIndex;` to initialize to the correct state. That's optional, as the value would be undefined, which is also not equal to `event.index`... Although if you needed to know previous for the first `tabChange` call, it would be necessary.